# Creating a shortcut to typing a spesific character on Xorg

Tags: fedora, xorg, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I've got a english keyboard, but sometimes I need to type turkish characters, like ç, ğ and ü. I'm thinking of this shortcuts:

> Pause + u -> ü

> Pause + c -> ç

And more like this. How can I create these shortcuts? I'm using Fedora 34, Cinnamon on Xorg

Comment: `Pause` isn't a modifier like `Shift` or `Control` or `Alt`. I mean computer does not expect `Pause` to be pressed with another key. So, one question: do you still need to use the key `Pause` on some contexts? I also think `Wayland` should appear in tag or title, because it does not work at all the same way on `X.org` and `Wayland`.

Comment: Pause key was just an example. I can use Shift, Alt, Control or another one. I also use Xorg, so I'll edit question.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to create or customize your keymap, however I'm going to point you to much better documentation of the process than I can provide.

[kboard_config_xorg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xorg/Keyboard_configuration)

[keyboard-how-too](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/pdf/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO.pdf)

This (despite it being arch and you on fedora) should contain all the information required to create a multi key binding that uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> = <kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> or what ever compose combination you need to produce.